# How do I access this variable outside the function?

Tags: python, function, numpy, jupyter

I am trying to re-use a variable that I defined in a function, but it keeps saying that the specific variable is not defined. How do I use the variable slope inside the function later on? Or how do I make it into a global variable?

```
def linear_fit_detrend(data):
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(years_trend, data)
    print('slope = ',slope)
    print('intercept =', intercept)
    print('r_value =', r_value)
    print('p_value =', p_value)
    print('stnrd error =', std_err)
    detrended = data - (years_trend*slope+intercept)
    return detrended

#using function

baff_lin = linear_fit_detrend(baff_last_25)

print(slope)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-cec786dbdcb3> in <module>
----> 1 print(slope)

NameError: name 'slope' is not defined
```

Comment: Can't you return it along with `detrended`?  The function in the first line is returning several variables.  Follow its example.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference - returning the tuple is the recommended method; the `global` works, but isn't the first choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among other solutions : declare the variable in the global scope and use it within your function. Then it will be accessible outside the function :

```
slope = 0

def linear_fit_detrend(data):
    global slope
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(years_trend, data)
    print('slope = ',slope)
    print('intercept =', intercept)
    print('r_value =', r_value)
    print('p_value =', p_value)
    print('stnrd error =', std_err)
    detrended = data - (years_trend*slope+intercept)
    return detrended

# using function
baff_lin = linear_fit_detrend(baff_last_25)
print(slope)
```

Answer (score 0):

try returning `[detrended,slope]` and `print(baff_lin[1])`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to have your function return multiple values

```
def linear_fit_detrend(data):
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(years_trend, data)
    print('slope = ',slope)
    print('intercept =', intercept)
    print('r_value =', r_value)
    print('p_value =', p_value)
    print('stnrd error =', std_err)
    detrended = data - (years_trend*slope+intercept)
    return detrended, slope

#using function

baff_lin, slope_var = linear_fit_detrend(baff_last_25)

print(slope_var)
```